# Is "foreshadowing" a countable noun or uncountable noun?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

In my book review, I want to express that "I find well-plotted foreshadowings, which indicate the inevitable tragedy". Is it correct or not?
By the way, should I use the word "indicate"?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foreshadowings&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforeshadowings%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cforeshadowings%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thanks for providing me with that useful website. I get it now: foreshadowing does have plural form.

Comment: @Fiona Of more particular relevance, is its [dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreshadowing) that shows it can take a plural form.

Comment: Be sure to click on some of the links along the bottom to see what usages are most idiomatic.